# How to computation mysql query results

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a mysql table as flows:

```
| ID | name   | number | date       |
| -- | ------ | ------ | ---------- |
| 1  | apple  | 2      | 2018-04-10 |
| 2  | orange | 3      | 2018-04-10 |
| 3  | apple  | 1      | 2018-04-11 |
| 4  | orange | 5      | 2018-04-11 |
```

I'd like to use a query compare the change of apple and orange during the day.

something like between 2018-04-10 to 2018-04-11, apple change value was -1 and orange was 3

Comment: `group by` and `sum` are what you want. Just need to add a `where` clause on `date` based on the parameters.

Comment: can you share the sql fiddle?

Comment: also post the expected output..

Comment: PS, unless I didn't get it, `orange` changed by `2`, not `3`... `5 - 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a self join.

**[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2882/4)** thanks to @terry

```
 SELECT t1.name, 
        t1.date as today, 
        t2.date as yesterday, 
        t1.number as today_value,
        t2.number as yesterday_value,
        t1.number - COALESCE(t2.number, t1.number) as difference

 FROM yourTable t1
 LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
   ON t1.date = DATE_ADD( t2.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND t1.name = t2.name
 ORDER BY  t1.name, t1.date
```

I add a condition so if you dont have the previous day consider there hasnt any change so difference is 0.

**OUTPUT**

```
|   name |      today |  yesterday | today_value | yesterday_value | difference |
|--------|------------|------------|-------------|-----------------|------------|
|  apple | 2018-04-10 |     (null) |           2 |          (null) |          0 |
|  apple | 2018-04-11 | 2018-04-10 |           1 |               2 |         -1 |
|  apple | 2018-04-12 | 2018-04-11 |          10 |               1 |          9 |
| orange | 2018-04-10 |     (null) |           3 |          (null) |          0 |
| orange | 2018-04-11 | 2018-04-10 |           5 |               3 |          2 |
| orange | 2018-04-12 | 2018-04-11 |          50 |               5 |         45 |
| orange | 2018-04-15 |     (null) |          10 |          (null) |          0 |
```

Comment: Made a SQL fiddle based on your answer, just in case OP wants to double check ;) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68bd24/1

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you see OP question he get -1

Comment: ok indeed never mind mine comment, didn't notice the dash before the 1 with the topicstarters question.

Comment: @terry I improve the query  to handle the case where you dont have the previous day.